# Given my bad shoulder, what can I use to clean the inside of my windshield?

Tags: cleaning, windshield

Does anyone have an idea of how to wash the inside of the windshield with something with a handle or equivalent?

I'm an older lady, with a bad shoulder, and can't seem to be able to reach my whole windshield. It's especially difficult on the driver's side.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

With a quick stroke of the pen (keyboard) using the Google, a search for "inside windshield cleaner" came up with a number of results. It looks like a shower back scrubber with a different name, but the concept is similar.

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M68CX91) has them, eBay has them, even Walmart has them.

Maybe the sponge type for the back scrubber in the shower isn't a great idea, though.

[image: inside cleaner]

Comment: These work great.  I have one with a triangular shaped head that gets into the corners very well.  Bad shoulder or not, it's hard to get to all of a high-sloping windshield.